# RoR - add content in relation to other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes

so i have got two models with each one controller:

`Model Project has_many Themes`

`Model Theme belongs_to Project`

in my routes file i added `resources :projects` and also for themes. Now i can add a project with `localhost/projects/new` which works fine and i can add Themes with `localhost/themes/new`. But thats not the way i want.

I only want to add Themes related to a project. Whats the best way to do this? I tried something like this: `match "projects/:project_id/themes/new" => 'themes#new', :as => 'themes'` which seems to work, but after submitting my new form nothing happens. the new form gets rendered again without a error message or something like that. my form tag in html gets rendered as the following:

`<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/projects/3/themes/new" class="new_theme" id="new_theme" method="post">`

do you have any ideas what went wrong? is there a best practice for something like that, because i think its a often wanted model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation is called nested resources.

In your routes define:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :themes
end
```

It will create exactly the url you described, as well as a bunch of helper methods. See [the rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) for a complete list, but here's an example:

To reach a single theme you would use `projects_theme_path(@project, @theme)`, or to view all the themes for a project you would use `projects_themes_path(@project)`. Again, see the rails guides for the full explanation and all the helpers.

Also, at any time you can run `rake routes` to see the EXACT helper methods as they are set up for your project.

Comment: that looks good! also the `rake routes` hint is a nice addition. one more thing: i added this and it works fine. now in my new action `<% form_for @theme do |f| %>` raises an error `No route matches {:controller=>"themes", :action=>"create"}`. do i have to modify my form_for action?

Comment: You need to use `form_for [@project, @theme] do |f|`. You might want to watch this railscast for more about how nested resources work: http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources

Comment: No prob, have fun with rails!

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

```
resources :projects do
  resources :themes
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources which makes modeling and implementing these routes stupid simple.

Comment: Using a plugin in place of core rails functionality that does exactly what he is looking for is overkill, and certainly not a good idea for a beginner who didn't know about nested routes. It's important to learn how the rails core works before layering in extra complexity with a gem.

Comment: I disagree.  Knowing what your options are is better than not knowing.  Who am I to assume that inherited_resources is over his head or overkill for his particular project?  I merely stated he should check it out, not use it.

Comment: Fair enough, Inherited Resources is worth looking at down the road, but passing on a side note is more appropriate as a comment than as an answer.

Comment: You're right.  I'm new to StackOverflow so I'm still getting the hang of things.